# Selecting images from Flickr and storing them in a Database using PHP

Tags: php, database

I am working on a piece of code that prints images from Flickr.
Based on the input from the user the code looks for the corresponding images.

Once the images are printed on the page, I would like to be able to make a selection, and save the selection to either the database or somewhere else I could retrieve them in order to edit them or eventually use them in a make your own collage page.

The code i'm using to retrieve the Flickr images is the following:

```
<?php
//choices of tags, number of pictures, tag search based on given tags
//send back in Json format and decode json
    $api_key = '4eb66ae95c7e8fb8dd729ebf61541d79';
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $tag1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['tag1']);
    $tag2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['tag2']);
    $tag3 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['tag3']);
    $tag = $tag1.",".$tag2.",".$tag3;

    $perPage = 25;
    $url = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search';
    $url.= '&api_key='.$api_key;
    $url.= '&tags='.$tag;
    $url.= '&per_page='.$perPage;
    $url.= '&format=json';
    $url.= '&nojsoncallback=1';

    $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
    $photo_array = $response->photos->photo;

     //check each photo from server, and specifiy url to print   
    foreach($photo_array as $single_photo)
    {

        $farm_id = $single_photo->farm;
        $server_id = $single_photo->server;
        $photo_id = $single_photo->id;
        $secret_id = $single_photo->secret;
        $size = 'm';

        $title = $single_photo->title;

        $photo_url = 'http://farm'.$farm_id.'.staticflickr.com/'.$server_id.'/'.$photo_id.'_'.$secret_id.'_'.$size.'.'.'jpg';

        print "<img title='".$title."' src='".$photo_url."' />";

    }
    }

?>
```

So my question is, is there a way to make the printed images clickable/selectable and/or a way to store the images, using either a DB or something?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your question is too broad for SO, but here are some tips.

Firstly, put some class on your img tags

```
print_r "<img class="clickable" title='".$title."' src='".$photo_url."' />"
```

Use AJAX to send the photo url to another PHP page. Here are a example using jQuery.

```
$('.body').on('click', '.clickable', function (){
    //use on because your <img> is dynamic
    var photo_url = $(this).prop('src);
    $.ajax({
            url: 'myApp/saveImg.php',
            data: {'url': photo_url},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(){
                alert('ok');
            }
            error: function(){
                alert('error');
            }                
});
```

Your saveImg.php is

```
$img_url = $_POST['url'];
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=ip_number;port=port_number;dbname=dbname", 'user', 'pass', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8'));
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO table_name VALUES("'.$img_url.'")';
        $result = $con->query($sql);
 return 'URL inserted';
```

Something like this. Try to adapt to your needs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the insight on how to possibly do this. I know it's a broad questions. I was just wondering if there's a way and if so, if it's easy and i just don't know it or advanced stuff. I'm gonna try and mess around with your idea for a bit and see where it'll get me!